# »Es gibt kein x, für das gilt: …« – Kommasetzung

Tags: comma, relative-clause

Setzt man hier ein Komma?

> Es gibt kein *x***,** für das gilt: …

Oder muss es folgendermaßen geschrieben werden?

> Es gibt kein *x* für das gilt: …

Answer (score 8):

Man setzt ein Komma. Du kannst die entsprechende Regel hier nachschlagen:

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Nebensatz.html)

Wenn Dir das noch nicht hilft, ergänze Deine Frage bitte um entsprechende Details.

Answer (score 4):

Deine Konstruktion ist ein normaler Relativsatz, wobei zusätzlich zum Relativpronomen noch eine Präposition gebraucht wird. Da ein Relativsatz ein Nebensatz ist, wird er durch ein Komma abgetrennt.

Als simple Merkregel bietet sich an:

> Zwischen zwei finiten Verben steht meistens ein Komma.

Comment: Regeln, in denen Wörter wie "meistens", "manchmal", "selten" oder "gelegentlich" vorkommen mögen zwar der Realität entsprechen, haben aber nur begrenzten Nutzen wenn man feststellen will, ob ein konkreter Fall richtig oder falsch ist. Da helfen Regeln, in denen "immer" oder "nie" steht, deutlich mehr.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Stimmt, aber ich wollte auch nur eine Faustregel an die Hand geben. Der einzig nennenswerte Gegenfall ist »zwei Nebensätze, die mit *und, oder, …* verbunden sind« und selten genug.

Answer (score 0):

Nebensätze (wie Relativsätze) werden vom Hauptsatz durch Komma abgetrennt.

Allerdings stellt sich die Frage hier eigentlich nicht. Es muss nämlich heißen:

> Für alle x gilt: ...

und anstelle der drei Punkte das Gegenteil von dem, was im Originalsatz ausgelassen wurde.

Comment: Diese Umstellung gilt aber wirklich nur in einem streng mathematischen Kontext; sobald Du eine vergleichbare Aussage in Alltagssprache machen willst, ist das "für alle X gilt" nicht absolut genug, solnage Du nicht explizit ein "es gibt keine Ausnahme" hinzufügst.

Comment: Von "müssen" kann wohl kaum die Rede sein. Je nach Komplexität von x kann es auch durchaus schwierig sein, das Gegenteil zu formulieren.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Wenn etwas für **alle** x gilt, gibt es keine Ausnahme. Ansonsten gilt es höchsten für die meisten x. Ich halte einen mathematischen Kontext für eine Aussage in dieser Form für höchst wahrscheinlich. So spricht ja kein Mensch in Alltagssprache.

Comment: @johnl Das Gegenteil dürfte kaum schwieriger zu formulieren sein als die eigentliche Aussage. Die Aussage kann ja nur behauptet werden, wenn klar ist, welche Eigenschaften kein x haben kann.

Comment: @Olafant Das Wort **alle** hat nur in einem streng mathematischen Kontext wirklich diesen Absolutheitsanspruch. In einer Aussage wie "alle 80 Millionen Deutsche haben eine Krankenversicherung" muss man sich immer ein "(fast) alle" oder "(nahezu) alle" denken, was deutlich stärker ist als "die meisten" aber nicht "alle ohne eine einzige Ausnahme" bedeutet. Alltagssprache ist eben *nicht* mathematisch exakt.

Comment: Die Aussage "es existiert kein Mensch, der 5 Arme hat" würde aber eine komplizierte Beschreibung bei Umdrehung der Aussage erfordern, sofern Du nicht zu einem auch eher schwammigen "alle haben weniger als 5" Zuflucht nehmen willst.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf *Alle* heißt auch in Alltagssprache *alle*. Ansonsten müsste explizit auf Ausnahmen hingewiesen werden. Das passiert i.d.R. auch z.B. mit dem Zusatz *Ausnahmen bestätigen die Regel*. Das ist aber gar nicht die Frage. Der Ausgangssatz ist doch keine Alltagssprache.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Um auf die eigentliche Frage zurückzukommen, würde die Aussage lauten: Es exisitiert kein Mensch, für den gilt: hat 5 Arme. So spricht kein Mensch in Alltagssprache. Falls aber doch: wie wäre es mit *Menschen haben höchstens 2 Arme*? Oder wäre das alltagssprachlich zu ungenau, weil die drei- und vierarmigen Menschen fehlen? ;)

Comment: @Olafant Um nicht den *Kommentare sind nicht für Diskussionen*-Hinweis zu provozieren, wird dies hier mein definitv letzter Beitrag zu diese Thema sein. Beispiel: Im Normalfall haben menschen 2 Arme. Aufgrund von Verlust durch Unfall, Amputation oder Misbildung gibt es auch Menschen mit einem oder keinem Arm. Durch Gendefekt (Spekulation, hab's nicht recherchiert) kommen auch Menschen mit 3 oder in ganz seltenen Fällen 4 Armen vor. 5 oder noch mehr Arme hat kein Mensch. Wenn Du jetzt den letzten Satz auf Dein Schema umformulieren willst, klingt es bestenfalls umständlich oder lahm.